# Search a list of word in SQL server 2008 without full text search

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I've a weird request but we must deal with these kinds of situation sometimes : I've to implements a word search in a SQL Server 2008 database. Good fit for full text search. But there's the trick : I can't use full text search because it's on a server I don't own and this feature is not installed (and probably will not be). So, basically I want to:

- Receive a comma separated list of words (easy !)
- I will check (with like) if the record contains the key word (easy too but I'm open to any suggestion to improve the performance of that operation)
- I want to have a count of these matches so I can order the result appropriately (???)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use scripting in my favorite language to make a separate table with three columns: word, count, recordID (pointing to a record in the first table). then all future searches could use that table for a faster search.

Comment: Yes, that could be a way but I'm looking for something more "tied" to the data like a view or something like that. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not the way I was looking for but I think I'll do it the way you suggest. Thanks for the hint.